# Closed form formula for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation

Is there a way of finding a formula for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^k$? Maybe I'm missing something really obvious, but I've looked around a bit on the Internet and I haven't been able to find anything.

So, what I'm looking for is a formula in closed form to generate the sequence $1,5,32,288,3413,\dots$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C32%2C288%2C3413+&language=english&go=Search) - it would appear there is no simple closed form.

The linked paper is available [here](http://www.ijpam.eu/contents/2007-36-2/9/9.pdf)

The given bound is

$$n^n\left( \frac{4n-3}{4n-4} \right) \le 1^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^n < n^n \left(\frac{2+e(n-1)}{e(n-1)}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, does that mean that a closed form is impossible? Or, that none has been found (yet)?

Comment: @Carolus - if by 'closed form' you mean in terms of 'elementary functions' I would say it is highly unlikely such a form exists (but do see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) as closed form is never really explicit!)

Answer (score 5):

The OEIS doesn't list a closed form for this sequence, only noting that $a_{n+1}/a_n>en$, and $a_{n+1}/a_n\to en$ as $n\to\infty$. There's also a list of the first 100 values of the sequence [here](http://oeis.org/A001923/b001923.txt).

Answer (score 4):

I would write the inequality as

$$
n^n\left( 1+\frac{1}{4(n-1)} \right) \le 1^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^n < n^n \left(1+\frac{2}{e(n-1)}\right)
$$

to better show the bounds.

Comment: Then why not $$
n^n\left( 1+\frac{2}{(n-1)}\frac18 \right) \le 1^1 + 2^2 + \cdots + n^n < n^n \left(1+\frac{2}{(n-1)}\frac1e \right)
$$