# Is there a formula to calculate the following sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I tried googling, but I may not be searching with correct terms.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^k = 1^1 + 2^2 +3^3 + 4^4 + \cdots + n^n$$

So, is there a formula to calculate this?

Comment: It's amazing how many times this question is repeated.

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/45066/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom I guess most people refer to google over the search option on this site. :/