# Why there isn't any formula to calculate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n{k^k}$ explicitly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, problem-solving, summation-method

I've looked over this [Closed form formula for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45066/closed-form-formula-for-sum-limits-k-1n-kk) but it doesn't have any explicit formula, only the bounds.

So, is it the case that no general formula can exist to calculate it or we haven't found any formula yet?

Comment: This sequence grows quite rapidly - obviously larger than any particular degree of polynomial - the terms eventually exceed this degree. What makes you think a closed form exists then? It looks like any such formula would have to be exponential or larger.

Comment: You should search the site before posting a duplicate:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45066/closed-form-formula-for-sum-limits-k-1n-kk

Comment: If you have looked over the other question then you should see that your actual question is also answered.

Comment: @StubbornAtom What do you mean? I've looked over the link and all it states is that there is no formula  to calculate this but it doesn't answer is it the case that we can never have such formula or we haven't found yet but will be in the future.

Comment: You can very well understand that a closed-form formula hasn't been found, which is clear from the discussions there. It's the same query of the OP of that question too.

Comment: My question is would it be ever found or is it impossible to found?

For example, uncertainity principle states that the position and velocity of a particle can't be measured simultaneously(below a certain level of certainity) and that is the property of the particle and not the limitation of humans.

Comment: Suppose that I was a famous mathematician and defined the polfosol's function as: $p(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n i^i$. Voila! here is _the_ closed form

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "explicit" formula. What you can ask is e.g.: Can this sum expressed by a term build up by polynomials and the functions ... (you should complement this). :-)